# Новостная лента (JS CSS HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Не так давно перешел на веб программирование с десктопа.

Стоит задача написать новостную ленту.
Как я вижу это
1) Из базы данных берутся данные. Возможно как то использовать JSON.
2) С помощью js через цикл данные добавляются в шаблон.
3) Шаблоны с данными добавляются в div в HTML

Сразу же возникает куча трудностей. Как сделать шаблон? Как добавить данные в шаблон и где хранить их до добавления на сайт? Даже прогуглить такое трудно для меня сейчас
Очень много всяких библиотек и даже не знаешь с какой начать. Возможно у кого то есть статья или кто-то сможет описать принцип.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Надо бы уже отдельную метку для проблем с гуглением завести, ибо ни JS, ни CSS, ни HTML в вопросе нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну тут есть несколько вариантов
1) Генерируем шаблон через JavaScript
   при помощи `document.createElement('...')`
   и `лепим DOM через appendChild()`
2) Handlebears js https://handlebarsjs.com/  тут все есть
3) Взять какой-нибудь фреймворк, например `vue.js`
   https://webformyself.com/kak-sozdat-spa-s-pomoshhyu-vue-js/